# Unicode issues in Org-mode

Tags: org-mode, unicode

Lately my documents dissolve into misinterpreted Unicode, for example α becomes \316\261. What could be the cause for that?

Comment: When you say "lately," do you mean that the same file was readable previously but is not readable now?  What have you changed recently?

Comment: I just found out that it happens upon restarting Emacs. It might be related to Spacemacs. Perhaps I should just create a GitHub issue.

Comment: The standard way to handle this sort of question is to start Emacs without your init file (`emacs -Q`) and then recursively bisect your init file (ie, iteratively comment out half of it) until you find out what's causing the problem.

Comment: Outch, this even happens with `emacs -Q` and it happens only with this particular file. Perhaps some special character throws the encoding detection off course?

Comment: Other editors have no problem decoding the file. I will try to produce a minimal example.

Comment: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=39949810377997626019

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emacs uses some heuristic to guess the encoding of the file. In this case it fails. No problem, just let Emacs know that the file uses `UTF-8` encoding. You can do that after visiting the file with `C-x RET r` or `M-x revert-buffer-with-coding-system`.  See `(info "(emacs) Specify Coding")` for details.